# Getting the SUM() of claps and at the same time counting bookmarks in one query

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I tried a lot of solution that looks similar to my problem but no one worked for me.

I have 5 tables:

**USERS** table:

```
+----+-------+----------------+-------------+------------+
| id |  name |     email      |    password |  register  |
+----+-------+----------------+-------------+------------+
|  1 | lofy  | hello@hi.com   |         123 | 2019-05-06 |
|  2 | jake  | jake@joke.com  |         123 | 2019-06-22 |
|  3 | moly  | moly@liky.com  |         123 | 2019-05-15 |
+----+-------+----------------+-------------+------------+
```

**POSTS** table:

```
+----+-------+-------------------+--------------+------------+
| id | title |       body        |    writer_id |    date    |
+----+-------+-------------------+--------------+------------+
|  1 | lofy  | blah blah blah..  |            1 | 2019-05-06 |
|  2 | jake  | blah blah blah..  |            2 | 2019-06-22 |
|  3 | moly  | blah blah blah..  |            2 | 2019-05-15 |
+----+-------+-------------------+--------------+------------+
```

**BOOKMARKED** table:

```
+---------+-----------+
| user_id |   post_id |
+---------+-----------+
|       1 |         1 |
|       2 |         2 |
|       3 |         2 |
+---------+-----------+
```

**CLAPS** table:

```
+---------+-----------+------------+
| user_id |   post_id | claps_times|
+---------+-----------+------------+
|       1 |         1 |          5 |
|       2 |         2 |         13 |
|       3 |         2 |          7 |
+---------+-----------+------------+
```

I used this query to get the posts details + the user name and avatar + how many times this post is bookmarked by the users

```
SELECT 
    posts.*, users.name, users.avatar , 
    COUNT(bookmarks.post_id) AS bookmarksCount   
FROM 
    posts 
LEFT JOIN 
    users ON users.id = posts.owner
LEFT JOIN
    bookmarks ON bookmarks.post_id = posts.id    
GROUP BY 
    posts.id;
```

Everything is OK so far.

The problem: I wanted to get the `SUM()` of the claps for each post so I added 2 more lines to the previous query, this is the query now:

```
SELECT posts.*, users.name, users.avatar , 
    count(bookmarks.post_id) as bookmarksCount ,
    SUM(claps.claps_count) AS totalClaps
    FROM posts 
    LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = posts.owner
    LEFT Join bookmarks ON bookmarks.post_id = posts.id
    LEFT JOIN claps ON claps.post_id = posts.id
    GROUP BY posts.id
    ;
```

The problem is that the result of the claps of the post.id "2" is doubled it's 40 instead of 20,

It's like the join of the count() of the bookmarks of the post is causing the problem, in other words if the sum() of the claps are 10 and the post is bookmarked 5 times after count() than the result of the claps will be 50 instead of 5.

I tried to subquery the sum() of the claps but I didn't know how to do it.

Can you please give me the solution in subquery way with a some explanation because I will add the count() of the comments later on and maybe more subqueries too

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to aggregate *before* doing the joins.  One method is:

```
SELECT p.*, u.name, u.avatar, 
       b.bookmarksCount, c.totalClaps
FROM posts p LEFT JOIN 
     users u
     ON u.id = p.owner LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT b.post_id, COUNT(*) as bookmarksCount
      FROM bookmarks b
      GROUP BY b.post_id
     ) b
     ON b.post_id = p.id LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT c.post_id, SUM(claps_count) as totalClaps
      FROM claps c
      GROUP BY c.post_id
     ) c
     ON c.post_id = p.id;
```

Note that no aggregation is needed in the outer query.

The above should have good performance if you are interested in all posts.  If you are filtering the posts by any criteria, then correlated subqueries are probably a better solution:

```
SELECT p.*, u.name, u.avatar, 
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM bookmarks b
        WHERE b.post_id = p.id
       ) as bookmarksCount,
       (SELECT SUM(claps_count)
        FROM claps c
        WHERE c.post_id = p.id
       ) as totalClaps
FROM posts p LEFT JOIN 
     users u
     ON u.id = p.owner LEFT JOIN
      b
     ON b.post_id = p.id;
```

For this, you want indexes on `bookmarks(post_id)` and `claps(post_id, claps_count)`.

Comment: TY A LOT .. the first query above give's a syntax error , the second one worked almost perfectly but gived me a duplicated rows , so i added ```DISTINCT``` , and now the result is perfect ... TY MAN